# How to check the status of AsyncTask in the following code?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

```
public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {
    ProgressBarHandler progressBarHandler;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

        progressBarHandler = new ProgressBarHandler(this);
        startTheDownload();
    }

    public void startTheDownload() {
        progressBarHandler.show();

        SaveDataOffline saveDataOffline = new SaveDataOffline(getApplicationContext());
        saveDataOffline.execute();
        AsyncTaskStopWords asyncTaskStopWords = new AsyncTaskStopWords(getBaseContext());
        asyncTaskStopWords.execute();

        if (saveDataOffline.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED && asyncTaskStopWords.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED) {
            progressBarHandler.hide();
            finish();
            Log.i("qwer", "finished");
            Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
            this.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried the following code but its not working it stuck with the progress bar

Comment: why do you need to do this? Async task has onPostExecute() method which you should be checking data for nulls, and perform additional work to update the UI. additionally you can update progress via AsyncTask as well please see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html which has a sample

Comment: I want to download some data before passing to next data so is there any way to check so .I want the status of async task in my splash screen

Comment: wait for the AsyncTask to finish if your waiting to download the data then

Comment: How will i know that async task is completed from  splash screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use get()

```
SaveDataOffline saveDataOffline = new SaveDataOffline(getApplicationContext());
saveDataOffline.execute().get();
AsyncTaskStopWords asyncTaskStopWords = new AsyncTaskStopWords(getBaseContext());
asyncTaskStopWords.execute().get();
```

Code will wait until `AsyncTask` finishes before going to the next line.